# Changes made in developer options revert back to default after turning off developer options

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, developer-options, gpu

I am trying to enable Force GPU rendering option in the developer options. But after enabling it and then turning off the developer options, the developer settings revert back to default. How do I make these changes stick permanently?

Using a Vivo Y53, Android Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep **developer options** running, simply don't turn **developer options** off. That's the only possible logical way.

Comment: But the thing is, some settings like the transition animation scale persist even after turning the developer options off, which might suggest that turning off the developer options might not necessarily be the culprit.

Comment: probably you have very old phone!

Comment: Yeah, well, I'm using Marshmallow. That might have something to do with it.